# Showing $(1+x)^r<(1+rx)$ (MVT)

Tags: calculus, inequality

So the full question goes as following:

Let $0<r<1$.

If $x>0$ or $-1\le x<0$, show that $(1+x)^r < (1+rx)$

I'm having a real hard time getting the idea of the usefullness of MVT. It seems every approach I take is faulty.

I don't know how to think.
If I take $f'(c)$ for $0<c<x$ I get $(1+c)r -1 / c$ which I can conclude is larger than $0$,  which leads me nowhere.

Help is very appriciated!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252629/generalization-of-bernoullis-inequality?rq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889077/deeper-understanding-mean-value-theorem-show-that-1xr1rx?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

**just a hint**

Let $F (x)=(1+x)^r-1-rx $

then $$F (x)=F (0)+xF'(c)$$

with

$$F'(c)=r ((1+c)^{r-1}-1)$$
$$=rc (r-1)(1+c')^{r-2} $$

Observe that $x $ and $c $ have the same sign.

Comment: Alright so I got:

$(1+x)^r = rx((1+c)^{r-1}+(1+rx)$ So im trying to prove $rx((1+c)^{r-1}$ is smaller than 1 essentially?

Comment: @AliasaZarownyPseudonymia You can use MVT a second time.

Comment: I noticed however for $(1+x)^r = rx((1+c)^{r-1}-1)+(1+rx)$ that 
$rx((1+c)^{r-1}-1)$ will always be negative since $(1+c)^{r-1}-1) = \frac{1}{(1+c)^{r-1}}-1 <0$ because $rx>0$ $rx((1+c)^{r-1}-1)<0$. Is that a legitimate reasoning? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=(1+x)^r$ and then $f'(x)=r(1+x)^{r-1}$.
Then by the MVT,
$$ f(x)-f(0)=f'(c)x, \text{ for some $c$ between $0$ and $x$}. \tag{1}$$
If $x>0$, then
$$ f'(x)=r(1+x)^{r-1}<r$$
and hence from (1), one has
$$ (1+x)^r-1=f'(c)x<rx $$
or 
$$ (1+x)^r<1+rx. $$
If $x\in(-1,0)$, then $0<1+x<1$ and hence $f'(x)=r(1+x)^{r-1}>r$. So 
$$ (1+x)^r-1=f'(c)x<rx $$
or
$$ (1+x)^r<1+rx. $$
for $x\in(-1,0)$.
Thus if $x\in(-1,0)\cup(0,\infty)$, one has
$$ (1+x)^r<1+rx. $$

Comment: thanks it was very easy to follow. However why the derivative of f'(x) pertinent, I see that you used it to find a relationship between $r(1+x)^{r-1}$ and $r$. But what does it mean? 

I know that usually it is to confirm whether the function is increasing from the starting point $f(0)$ or not. If it is increasing you can conclude that $f(x)>f(0)$ but what does $r(1+x)^{r-1}<r$ tell me?

Thank you btw

Comment: @AliasaZarownyPseudonymia, if $x>0$, then $1+x>1$ and hence $(1+x)^{r-1}<1$ since $r<1$,

Comment: I forumlated myself poorly; what is the rational of taking the derivative $f'(x)$?

Comment: How does $f'(x)<r$ imply $f'(c)<r$? (Sorry for bombarding you with questions)

Comment: @AliasaZarownyPseudonymia, $(1+x)^{r-1}<1$ implies $f'(x)=r(1+x)^{r-1}<r$ for $x>0$ and hence $f'(c)<r$.

Answer (score 1):

By any of the answers to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2545278/mvt-showing-1xr-1rx) (sma question, case $r>1$), we can set $r=\dfrac 1s,\; (s>1)$, we have
\begin{align}
&&(1+rx)^s&=\Bigl(1+\frac xs\Bigr)^s>1+s\cdot\frac xs=1+x\\
&\text{whence}&1+rx&>(1+x)^{\tfrac1s}=(1+x)^r.
\end{align}